# How do you call a python file that requires a command line argument from within another python file?

Tags: python, import, arguments, call

For example, I have two python files, `'test1.py'` and `'test2.py'`. I want to `import test2` into `test1`, so that when I run `test1`, it also runs `test2`.

However, in order to run properly, `test2` requires an input argument. Normally when I run `test2` from outside of `test1`, I just type the argument after the file call in the `command line`. How do I accomplish this when calling `test2` from within `test1`?

Comment: Without knowing how `test2` is structured, it's very difficult to say. If whoever wrote it factored the argument parsing into a separate function and/or used `if __name__ == '__main__'` properly, you can likely just bypass it and inject your parameter straight in. If not, you may have to fiddle with `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the ability of editing test2.py there are two options:

1. **(Possible to edit)** Pack test2.py content into class and pass args in init.

in **test1.py** file:

```
from test2 import test2class
t2c = test2class(neededArgumetGoHere)
t2c.main()
```

in **test2.py** file:

```
class test2class:
    def __init__(self, neededArgumetGoHere):
        self.myNeededArgument = neededArgumetGoHere

    def main(self):
        # do stuff here
        pass

# to run it from console like a simple script use
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t2c = test2class(neededArgumetGoHere)
    t2c.main()
```

2. **(Not possible to edit test2.py)** Run test2.py as a subprocess. Check subprocess [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more info how to use it.

**test1.py**

```
from subprocess import call

call(['path/to/python','test2.py','neededArgumetGoHere'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can define your own test1 and test2 and that you are OK with using argparse (which is a good idea anyway):

The nice thing with using argparse is that you can let test2 define a whole bunch of default parameter values that test1 doesn't have to worry about.  And, in a way, you have a documented interface for test2's calling.

Cribbed off https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

**test2.py**

```
import argparse

def get_parser():
    "separate out parser definition in its own function"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("square", help="display a square of a given number")
    return parser

def main(args):
    "define a main as the test1=>test2 entry point"
    print (int(args.square)**2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    "standard test2 from command line call"
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

**audrey:explore jluc$ python test2.py 3**

```
9
```

**test1.py**

```
import test2
import sys

#ask test2 for its parser
parser = test2.get_parser()

try:
    #you can use sys.argv here if you want
    square = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    #argparse expects strings, not int
    square = "5"

#parse the args for test2 based on what test1 wants to do
#by default parse_args uses sys.argv, but you can provide a list
#of strings yourself.
args = parser.parse_args([square])

#call test2 with the parsed args
test2.main(args)
```

**audrey:explore jluc$ python test1.py 6**

```
36
```

**audrey:explore jluc$ python test1.py**

```
25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the call or popen method from subprocess module.

```
from subprocess import call, Popen

Call(file, args)
Popen(file args)
```